# Retrieve button by findViewWithTag not working?

Tags: java, android

In the onCreate() method of my class I make a grid of buttons, and give them tags to identify them, for example:

```
button.setTag("one four");
```

This is working fine. Now I want to make a new temporary button within a method, and I'm using this code:

```
String s = "one four";
Object o = s;
View view = new View(this);
Button button = (Button)view.findViewWithTag(o);
```

But button always comes out as "null". And I don't know why.

Comment: Well, you have to add a button with that tag on your view first..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must call `view.addChild(button);` before  `view.findViewWithTag(o);`

And you dont need to do this `Object o = s;`,  `view.findViewWithTag(s);` will do the same.

`View view = new View(this);` - you create a new instance of `View`. 
Object `view` does not have any children. You must call `findViewWithTag(s)` method from layout which contains your `Button` object.

Comment: Like this: Button knop = view.addChild(Button)view.findViewWithTag(o); ?

Comment: no. button.setTag(s);view.addChild(button); Button button = (Button)view.findViewWithTag(s);

Comment: When I do that, I get the error: Button cannot be resolved to a variable. And I have imported both button and view.

Comment: That's is impossible to do before the line where I make "button". EDIT: Eclipse also says the method addChild() does not exists.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7072/discussion-between-mavix-and-natali)

Comment: there is no such method `addChild(View child)`, the correct is `addView(View child)`

Answer (score 1):

Try not assigning the string to the object variable and set the tag directly to be your string.

Answer (score 1):

Mavix, findViewWithTag traverse all child views and works fine in ViewGroup. Try this:

```
// after button.setTag("one four");

ViewGroup v = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.myFirstLayoutIdInXmlLayoutFile); 
Button b = (Button) v.findViewWithTag("one four");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same doubt. In my situation, I have a Main Layout and a Secondary Layout (inside the Main) - the two were RelativeLayout's - and I want to get the components I had added on the screen.

But I had to use dynamic keys (which could be repeated)and were the unique parameter I could use to Identify the components.

Like Natali, in her [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9020736/7414963), I use "TAG" in the components and worked for me. See below (using Button as example):

**Step 1:** Declare a button-type variable.  `Button btn = new Button(this)`; // this is Context of my Activity

**Step 2:** Set any key.  `String any_key = "keyToGetButton";`

**Step 3:** Set tag (key setted in step 2) to your button.  `btn.setTag(any_key);`

**Step 4:** Get your button by tag (in other method, for example).  `Button button = (Button)  your_layout_where_is_button.findViewWithTag(any_key);`